# Show/hide a layout on scroll up/down android

Tags: android, material-design

I am working on an android application and want to implement a functionality in which I want to show a layout which will contain Like/Comment of that content at the bottom of the page.
I want this layout to be shown when I scroll up the page and hide when I scroll down the page.

I have scene many applications that have implemented this feature, but I have no idea how to implement this feature in my app.
Please check this link of the app which is giving the same functionality which I want to implenment https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.midsizemango.materialapps

Please help if anyone have idea here, Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: The source code is available for this app in Github. If you're trying to get the scroll up/down listener of your `RecyclerView`, you might take a look at here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33007135/3145960

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please post the github source code link of the app here. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the same thing which happens with fab, first create a class extending`CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View>` and implement it like other fab examples. just remember that it won't work on simple listView and gridView.
Also [here](http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator)'s a good **detailed** tutorial for you.

Answer (score 0):

You Just have to set `Scroll-Up & Scroll-Down listener` of your Recycler view or Scroll View [check Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29024058/recyclerview-scrolled-up-down-listener).

Now base on Scroll-Up & Scroll-Down listener set `VISIBLE / GONE`of your footer view either it is LinearLayout or Toolbar with animation.