# Recycler View Detect Swipe Up and Down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can i set up my `RecyclerView` properly to detect swipe Up and Down?

When i place `recycler.setOnTouchListener(this)`
I get this warning: **recyclerview has setontouchlistener but does not override perfoclick**  and nothing works.

Thank you.

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
Adapter adapter=new  
Adapter (List);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: You can use the SwipeLayout for upside pull and And for the downside you can use the addOnScrollListener listener of the recyclview

Comment: maybe it help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29024058/recyclerview-scrolled-up-down-listener

Comment: Please read the question carefully. I want to detect Swipe not just scrolling

Comment: @Nick you will have to use onTouchListener(). And this warning has nothing to do with no clicking or anything. You should put a debugger and fine out the exact issue.

Comment: @Umair There is nothing wrong with the code. Recycler works fine ntil i put the touchListener. You should try it.

Comment: check this link maybe help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/48520345/9312502

Comment: @Nick  the problem is in your code. I have tried it and onTouchListener() is working fine. And about the warning you should read this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47107105/android-button-has-setontouchlistener-called-on-it-but-does-not-override-perform?rq=1 . As you cann see it has nothing to do with your problem

Comment: @Umair Then, If you are kind enough could you please share the code with us?

Comment: take a look at this code snippet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645537/how-to-detect-the-swipe-left-or-right-in-android . If that doesn't help then tell me.

Comment: @Umair The link you provided. implements the events to the whole Activity and not to the specific view. If you attach on recycler specifically you will get the warning.

Answer (score -2):

You should be using SwipeRefreshLayout and handle the callback with setOnRefreshListener example.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
   android:id="@+id/swRefresh"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
   android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


SwipeRefreshLayout mSwRefresh=findViewById(R.id.SwRefresh);;
mSwRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
   @Override
   public void onRefresh() {
    //TODO:
   }
});
```

Comment: I want also from bottom refresh

Comment: for botton refresh or both try using RecyclerView.OnScrollListener see link gist https://gist.github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/b65098bc17a88c7b8192